# How to create a Youtube style loading bar with Rails 4's Turbolinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, progress-bar, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Is there a way to make a Youtube style loading bar (the inter-page across the top bar) with turbo-links.

Turbolinks has loads of different callbacks so you could make a jumpy one across a few steps but is there a way to hook into the progress too?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[nprogress-rails](https://github.com/caarlos0/nprogress-rails) is probably just what you need.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the turbolinks life cycle.

Comment: We are using this ourselves now. @Smickie is incorrect, the gem has hooks to integrate and run the progress bar against several different techniques, specifically Turbolinks, Pjax & Ajax.

Comment: a very nice and easy to implement solution

Comment: Can confirm - works perfectly alongside turbolinks, and has Bootstrap theming too - a very simple fix.

Answer (score 16):

Check your turbolinks version:

```
$ gem list |grep turbolinks
turbolinks (2.5.3)
```

if your Turbolinks version < 3.0, add below code to you js file(for example: `application.js`).

```
Turbolinks.enableProgressBar();
```

if you are using Turbolinks 3.0, the progress bar is turned on by default.

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#progress-bar.

[image]

the  progress bar can be customized by CSS, just like:

```
html.turbolinks-progress-bar::before {
  background-color: red !important;
  height: 5px !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have Turbolinks set up correctly add [nProgress JS script](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) to your Rails app asset pipeline i.e the [JS](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress/blob/master/nprogress.js) and [CSS](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress/blob/master/nprogress.css).

Set up nProgress by adding this to your custom JS ...

```
$(document).on('page:fetch',   function() { NProgress.start(); });
$(document).on('page:change',  function() { NProgress.done(); });
$(document).on('page:restore', function() { NProgress.remove(); });
```

And that's it.

Ps: Check out the [nProgress Github page](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress#nprogress) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Was brought up in https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/265

Won't be added to Turbolinks, but shows you a simple reference for how to add it if you need to.

Comment: Would this mean branching the turbolinks js or could you add it to the normal js file?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another brilliant JS from Hubspot, called Pace.

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays a ProgressBar is included with turbolinks (v.2.5.3)

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery Plugin Called NG Progress JS seem to be having the support for turbo links.
Here are the NG Progress & alternatives.

http://www.webiyo.com/2013/09/youtube-style-ajax-progress-bar-using.html

Hope It Helps.