# Rails 4: turbo-links change mouse cursor when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, rails-4-2-1

when using rails 4 turbo-links,
how do you change the mouse cursor to progress when a link is clicked?

i have tried this with no success:

> application.js.erb

```
$(function() {
    $(window).ajaxStart(function() {
       $(this).css({'cursor' : 'progress'});
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
       $(this).css({'cursor' : 'default'});
    });
});
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you in production mode?

Comment: @Dinesh Saini: no, this is on my local development,
is there a difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042191/turbolinks-what-is-the-rails-4-way-of-showing-progress-for-slow-pages
Check this one

Answer (score 1):

I found a jquery patch to help, although i wonder if there is a better solution..

in the mean time [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321131/how-to-create-a-youtube-style-loading-bar-with-rails-4s-turbolinks/18815206#18815206) helped me:

> application.js.erb

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('page:fetch',   function() { $('body').css( 'cursor', 'progress' ); });
    $(document).on('page:change',  function() { $('body').css( 'cursor', 'default' ); });
});
```